# Are there pre-setup Grafana Dashboards to view GKE Billing Export?

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana

I've set up Billing Export to BigQuery in GKE and also set up a grafana data source for it.
Now I'd like to create a dashboard, but first,​ check if there are preexisting ones.

Comment: as an inspiration you can use the picture from here: https://grafana.com/blog/2019/06/25/community-spotlight-bigquery-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It's fun to see, I originally tried to recreate just that, but found the picture in a different part of the internet. Couldn't quite get there, since I still lack some skill